# How to cite a technical report for a double blind review process?

Tags: peer-review

Some conferences follow the double-blind review process. As such, you cannot reveal your identity to the reviewers. Further, these conferences restrict the number of pages, say to at most 8 pages.

I am facing the following problem: I would like to submit a paper to some of these conferences but I have a paper that is 10-pages long; containing 2 pages of appendices (proofs). I am thinking to write a technical report and put these appendices in it. So now I have the paper to submit (8 pages) which of course cites the technical report (10 pages). How can I cite the technical report to not violate the double-blind review process?

Comment: The best thing for you to do is contact the individual venues and ask what their preferences are. Some venues allow you to submit auxiliary documentation and data, which would be a good way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to suggest it here, but in some ways your best option is to work to rewrite the paper within the page limits. It can be a difficult task to use fewer words without losing meaning, but it is part of the history of good writing to work at that. George Bernard Shaw famously said "I'm sorry this letter is so long, I didn't have time to make it shorter."

Mathematical proofs, if that is what it is, can often be shortened, especially if the techniques are standard and the audience is sophisticated.

But the prose in the other ten pages may be more amenable to reworking.

If you can do it the reviewers will be happier as will the rest of your audience.

Comment: That wasn't the case here though, @user49915. It was shortening by a couple of pages. On the other hand, reviewers expecting an 8 page paper aren't going to be all that happy when the "real" thing is 53 pages. Easy reject, I think. They would just suggest a more suitable venue.